# C# название метода переменной

Tags: c#, ооп

Хочу сделать класс с методами букв алфавита. вот что вышло:

```
public class Sort {
        string[] a = new string[100000]; string[] b = new string[100000]; string[] c = new string[100000];
        string[] d = new string[100000]; string[] e = new string[100000]; string[] f = new string[100000];
        string[] g = new string[100000]; string[] h = new string[100000]; string[] i = new string[100000];
        string[] j = new string[100000]; string[] k = new string[100000]; string[] l = new string[100000];
        string[] m = new string[100000]; string[] n = new string[100000]; string[] o = new string[100000];
        string[] p = new string[100000]; string[] q = new string[100000]; string[] r = new string[100000];
        string[] s = new string[100000]; string[] t = new string[100000]; string[] u = new string[100000];
        string[] v = new string[100000]; string[] w = new string[100000]; string[] x = new string[100000];
        string[] y = new string[100000]; string[] z = new string[100000];
        string field;
    }
```

Теперь я хочу к ним обращаться по первой букве со строки. К примеру:

```
data_sort.((data_sort[i]).Substring(0, 1))[i] = "no";
```

Возможно ли такое на C#?

Comment: Можно `Dictionary<>` и  `KeyValue<>`

Comment: На сколько слов хотите словарь? Есть риск столкнуться с OutOfMemory. Используйте субд, или делайте уже "древесный"

Comment: ой спасибо) это то, что нужно

Answer (score 1):

(*Вынесено из комментариев*)

Проще всего воспользоваться `Dictionary<char, List<string>>`. Это даст вам возможность искать по первой букве, а также использует `List<string>` динамического размера, вместо огромного статически выделенного массива `string[100000]`.

Ваш пример кода будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
char firstLetter = word[0];
List<string> words = dict[firstLetter];
words[i] = "no";
```